# Laplace transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform, applications, regularization

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}\mathbb{D}_t^\beta u(x, y, t)=-a(x)\left(u_x(x, y, t)+u_y(x, y, t)\right)+\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t)), & x>0, y>0, t>0 \\ u(x, y, 0)=0, & x>0, y>0 \\ \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} u(x, y, t)=0, & y>0, t>0 \\ u(1, y, t)=u_1(y, t), & y>0, t>0\end{cases}(1)
\end{equation}

where $\beta \in(0,1)$ is fixed, and $\mathbb{D}_t^\beta$ is denoted the Caputo fractional derivative with respect to $t$ defined by

$$
\mathbb{D}_t^\beta g(t):=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\beta)} \int_0^t \frac{\partial g(\kappa)}{\partial \kappa} \frac{\mathrm{d} \kappa}{(t-\kappa)^{\beta}}
$$

Here $a \in C[0,1]$ is a space-dependent diffusion coefficient satisfying $a_{*} \leq a(x) \leq a^{*}, x \in[0,1]$ for some positive real numbers $a_{*}$ and $a^{*}$, and $\ell$ is the nonlinear function which will be defined later.

Now, applying the Laplace transform to the first and second equations of (1) with respect to $y$ and $t$, according to the properties of the Laplace transform of the Caputo derivative, we obtain
$$\mathcal L\mathbb{D}_t^\beta u(x, y, t)=\mathcal L[-a(x)(u_{x}(x, y, t)+u_y(x, y, t))+\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t)]$$
Applying $$
\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\mathrm{d}^n f(t)}{\mathrm{d} t^n}, t, s\right\}=s^n F(s)-\sum_{k=1}^n s^{n-k} f^{(k-1)}(0)
$$ 
and $$\begin{gathered}L\left\{{ }_0^C D_t^p f(t)\right\}=s^p F(s)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} s^{p-k-1} f^{(k)}(0),  (n-1<p \leq n), \end{gathered}$$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal L\mathbb{D}_t^\beta u(x, y, t)&=s_2^\beta \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_1, s_2\right)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1-1} s_2^{1-0-1}{u} (x, y, 0)\\&=s_2^\beta \widetilde{u}(x, s_1, s_2)-{u}(x, y, 0)\\
    &=s_2^\beta \widetilde{u}(x, s_1, s_2)\quad \text{since} \quad  u(x, y, 0)=0
\end{align*}
và $$
\begin{aligned}
    &\mathcal L\left[-a(x)(u_x(x, y, t)+u_y(x, y, t))+\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t))\right]\\&=-a(x)\left[\mathcal L(u_x(x, y, t)+\mathcal Lu_y(x, y, t)) +\mathcal L\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t))\right]\\
\end{aligned} 
$$
With $\mathcal L(u_{x}(x, y, t)=\widetilde{u}_x\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)$ \
và $\mathcal Lu_{y}(x, y, t))=s_{1} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1} s_1^{1-1}{u}\left(x, 0, t\right)=s_{1} \widetilde{u}(x, s_1, s_2)- u(x, 0, t)$\
$\mathcal L \left[\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t))\right]=\widetilde \ell(x, s_1, s_2, u(x, s_1, s_2)) $\
So $$
\begin{aligned}
    &\mathcal L\left[-a(x)(u_{x}(x, y, t)+u_{y}(x, y, t))+\ell(x, y, t, u(x, y, t))\right]\\&=-a(x)\left[\widetilde{u}_x\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)+s_{1} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)-u\left(x, 0, t\right) \right]+\widetilde \ell(x, s_1, s_2, u(x, s_1, s_2))
\end{aligned}$$
So we have $$s_2^\beta \widetilde{u}(x, s_1, s_2)=-a(x) \left[\widetilde{u}_x(x, s_1, s_2)+s_{1} \widetilde{u}(x, s_1, s_2)-u(x, 0, t)\right]+\widetilde \ell(x, s_1, s_2, u(x, s_1, s_2)) $$
\textbf{conditions are still lacking} $u(x, 0, t)=0$}???

So
$$
s_{2}^{\beta} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)=-a(x)\left(\widetilde{u}_{x}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)+s_{1} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)\right)+\widetilde{\ell}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}, u\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)\right),
$$

$$
s_{2}^{\beta} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)=-a(x)\left(\widetilde{u}_{x}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)+s_{1} \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)\right)+\widetilde{\ell}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}, u\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)\right),\quad (2)
$$
where  $ \widetilde{u}\left(x, s_{1}, s_{2}\right)$  denotes the Laplace transform $u\left(x, y, t\right)$ and $s_{1}, s_{2}$ are the variables of the Laplace transform on $y, t$, respectively.

\author{
Dinh Nguyen Duy Hai \ Department of Economic Mathematics, Ho Chi Minh University of Banking, Ho Chi Minh City, Viet Nam
}

How to transform equation (1) to get (2)?

Comment: s the hypothesis of the problem missing?u(x,0,t)=0???

Comment: Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What is your question exactly? I see you applied LT to (1) to get (2)?